# What randomness algorithm does Yoroi use for wallet generation?

Tags: yoroi, randomness

What randomness algo does Yoroi use for the wallet generation? Interested in seeing how secure it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoroi is using the [`bip39` JavaScript library](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39) to generate the mnemonic.

When we look at [its code](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39/blob/master/src/index.js#L139-L146), we can discover the generation is actually pretty simple:

```
function generateMnemonic(strength, rng, wordlist) {
    strength = strength || 128;
    if (strength % 32 !== 0) {
        throw new TypeError(INVALID_ENTROPY);
    }
    rng = rng || randomBytes;
    return entropyToMnemonic(rng(strength / 8), wordlist);
}
```

We see that as no random number generator (`rnd`) is defined, it uses the [`randombytes` library](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/randombytes) by default, which is in place using the [Crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) function that is provided from your browser.

To sum this up, Yoroi is using randomness algorithm of your browser, which - depending on the browser - is your system-level entropy source.